# In java/jdbc do you have to call commit after doing a select if you include "for fetch only with ur" in db2?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

In zos db2, if you don't specify any isolation-level-changing clauses in the sql, you will create a lock when you do a select, for which you then have to call commit or rollback or you will be tying up resources.

I was wondering (I tried to read the docs but it's not clear on the subject) if you specify "for fetch only with ur" then supposedly db2 acquires no locks and therefore I shouldn't have to formally end the transaction.

Anybody know if this is true or can point me to some documentation where it's actually clear about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query with  "for fetch only with ur" would not normally place any locks on the queried tables, however, it may place internal locks on the catalog tables, which would prevent someone from dropping the table that's being queried. Normally you should issue a `commit` after any transaction, I don't really understand why you are averse to doing that.

Comment: millions of lines of legacy code that I'm all of a sudden doing lots of new selects on lots of tables across threads that are already in the middle of transactions that are not yet ready to be committed. Probably I should just make my own connection and use that, and commit that.